# Why is a route not reactive?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-component, vuejs3, reactive-programming

As part of my [Quasar app](https://quasar.dev/), I have the following route:

```
import { RouteRecordRaw} from 'vue-router'
import { uid } from 'quasar'

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: () => {
      console.log('matched /')
      return {path: `/${uid()}`}
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/:uuid',
    component: () => import('pages/User.vue')
    // component: User,
  },
];

export default routes;
```

This works fine when going to `/`: the URL is changed to `/73a219e5-2cf2-4dd0-8...` and `User.vue`  is executed (specifically there a `fetch` inside that retrieves some data based on the `:uuid` parameter.

If I force a route from within a component (`User.vue` for instance), via

```js
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()
router.push('/')
```

I do see that the URL changes to a new UUID but `User.vue` is not executed. Specifically, a reference to `route.params.uuid` where `const route = useRoute()` is not reactive.

Is this normal (= I have to look for anther way to trigger), or is there a misuse (erroneous use) on my side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of the issue is that you're (re)using the same component for rendering the page you're navigating ***from*** and the page you're navigating ***to***.

By design, Vue optimises DOM rendering and will reuse the existing component instance. This means certain hooks won't be triggered (e.g: `mounted`, `created`, etc...) when changing route.

To force Vue into creating a different component instance when the route changes, use the current route's `.fullPath` as `key` on `<router-view>`:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <router-view :key="route.fullPath"></router-view>
  ...
</template>
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute();
</script>
```